# Exact sequence extracted from projective resolution

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $\textbf P$ be projective resolution of a module. Why is the sequence $P_{n+1}\xrightarrow{\partial_{n+1}}P_n\xrightarrow{\overline{\partial}}B_{n-1}\rightarrow 0$ exact, where $B_{n-1}=B_{n-1}(\textbf P)$ and $\partial_n$ factors as $P_n\xrightarrow{\overline{\partial}} B_{n-1}\xrightarrow{i} P_{n-1}$?

I dont't see why $\ker \overline{\partial}\subseteq \mathrm{im}\ \partial_{n+1}$.

Comment: That is the way the projective resolution is *inductively* built.

Comment: Oh, we have $H_n(\textbf P)=0$ for $n\geq 1$, when $\textbf P$ is projective resolution of a module, is that right?

Comment: By definition, projective resolutions are exact sequences.

Comment: $\ker \overline{\partial} = \ker\partial_n=\operatorname{im}\partial_{n+1}$, because $i$ is injective.

Comment: Yes, because the initial short exact sequence splits.